# How to use DateTime.TryParseExact within a LINQ statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, tryparse

Given the following source data:

```
Dim inputs = {New With {.Name="Bob", .Date="201405030500"},
              New With {.Name="Sally", .Date="201412302330"},
              New With {.Name="Invalid", .Date="201430300000"}}
```

I have written the following LINQ query (with the intention of adding a `Where success` clause as a filter before the `Select`, but I've left it out and have included `success` in the results for debugging purposes):

```
Dim result1 = From i in inputs
              Let newDate = New DateTime
              Let success = DateTime.TryParseExact(i.Date, "yyyyMMddHHmm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, newDate)
              Select New With {
                  .Name = i.Name, 
                  .Success = success,
                  .Date = newDate
              }
```

However, I get the following results, with the `newDate` not getting populated by the `TryParseExact`:

[image: Results without a parsed Date]

So, I refactored the query to extract the `TryParseExact` into an anonymous method to get the following:

```
Dim parseDate = Function(d As String)
                    Dim parsedDate As DateTime
                    Return New Tuple(Of Boolean, Date)(DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "yyyyMMddHHmm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, parsedDate), parsedDate)
                End Function

Dim result2 = From i in inputs
              Let parsedDate = parseDate(i.Date)
              Select New With {
                  .Name = i.Name,
                  .Success = parsedDate.Item1,
                  .Date = parsedDate.Item2
              }
```

...and this correctly gives me:

[image: Results with a parsed Date]

However, I'd like to find a way to do this entirely within the LINQ statement without the need to use an anonymous method to create a tuple.  Sure, I've got something that works, but I'd like to do this as a point of academic interest.

I suspect this may be possible, but my question is:

Why doesn't the `result1` query properly set `newDate` with the parsed date?

(I've considered lazy evaluation, but I don't think it applies here.)

**Update:**

- Thank you [Hamlet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685467/hamlet-hakobyan) for showing me that you can actually declare and invoke an anonymous method at the same time!  Mind = Blown!
- Thank you [Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112139/jim-wooley) for suggesting a Nullable instead of a Tuple!  Makes a lot of sense.
- Thank you [Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59111/ahmad-mageed) for suggesting the closure, that is certainly cleaner to me than the anonymous method.

Because of the answers below, I've refactored the LINQ as follows (including the `Where` clause filter):

```
Dim result3 = From i in inputs
              Let parsedDate = Function(d) 
                                   Dim dtParsed As DateTime
                                   Return If(DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "yyyyMMddHHmm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, dtParsed), dtParsed, New DateTime?)
                               End Function(i.Date)
              Where parsedDate.HasValue
              Select New With {
                  .Name = i.Name,
                  .Date = parsedDate.Value
              }
```

[image: Results with a parsed Date]

This achieves what I'm looking for, and I'm trusting the compiler to optimize the heck out of the generated code, but I'd still like to understand exactly why `result1` doesn't work.  Perhaps that's a question for Eric Lippert or John Skeet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [TryParsers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TryParsers) library which was created especially to use `TryParse` methods in LINQ queries.

```
Dim query = From i In inputs
    Let d = TryParsers.TryParse.DateTimeExact(i.Date, "yyyyMMddHHmm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal)
    Select New With {
          .Name = i.Name,
          .Success = Not d Is Nothing,
          .Date = d.Value
    }
```

You can not use range variables (`let`) as ref / out parameters because `let` keyword creates a *read only* variable (actually it compiles to a property of anonymous object).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question about the `Let` clause in a comment above, as well as introducing me to the TryParsers library.  This looks much nicer.

Comment: You might want to consider checking `.Success = Not d.HasValue()` instead of `Not d Is Nothing`

Comment: @JimWooley there is no difference

Answer (score 2):

Rather than declare `newDate` in a `Let` clause, you can pull it off by declaring `newDate` outside of the query. Then your query would reference it as you did originally.

```
Dim newDate As New DateTime
Dim query = From i in inputs
            Let success = DateTime.TryParseExact(i.Date, "yyyyMMddHHmm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, newDate)
            Select New With {
              .Name = i.Name, 
              .Success = success,
              .Date = newDate
          }
```

For what it's worth, in C# we'd need to use the `out` keyword for the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method. Attempting to use `newDate` with a `let` clause, similar to the first example, would result in the C# compiler generating an error:

> Cannot pass the range variable 'newDate' as an out or ref parameter

Comment: C# has no problem with that kind of code and at all. Here are two implementations both with closure and with delegate. http://pastebin.com/CNeL54AT

Comment: @HamletHakobyan based on your code we're in agreement. My comment about C# refers to attempting to use `newDate` in the LINQ query using a `let` clause, like the OP did in their first snippet... `let newDate = ...`. I've updated my comment since it was unclear. Thanks!

Comment: This is closer to what I'm looking for, although it introduces a (harmless) closure.  What I'd still like to understand is why the Let clause won't work.  (If it could work, it would reduce the scope of the `newDate` variable to within the LINQ expression itself.)

Comment: >What I'd still like to understand is why the Let clause won't work.
Because `let` keyword creates a "readonly" variable (actually it compiles to a property of anonymous object).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using Nullable Date for the .Date property and leave the .Success to be an evaluation of the DateTime?.HasValue. You would then need to modify your parseDate lambda to return the nullable as follows:

```
Dim inputs = {New With {.Name="Bob", .Date="201405030500"},
              New With {.Name="Sally", .Date="201412302330"},
              New With {.Name="Invalid", .Date="201430300000"}}

Dim parseDate = Function(d As String)
                    Dim parsedDate As DateTime? = DateTime.Now
                    If DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "yyyyMMddHHmm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, parsedDate) Then
                        Return parsedDate
                    Else
                        Return Nothing
                    End If
                End Function

Dim result2 = From i in inputs
              Select New With {
                  .Name = i.Name,
                  .Date = parseDate(i.Date)
              }
```

I would actually move the parseDate out from a lambda to static helper method so that you could reuse it easier elsewhere in your code.

```
Public Shared Function parseDate(d as String) as DateTime?
   Dim parsedDate As DateTime? = DateTime.Now
   If DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "yyyyMMddHHmm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, parsedDate) Then
       Return parsedDate
   Else
       Return Nothing
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: You cannot pass `TryParseExact` a `Nullable(Of DateTime)` as parameter because it is an `out` parameter (comparable to `ByRef`), but letting the function return a nullable value is a good idea.

Comment: You can if you set it to a default value before calling TryParseExact (hence the `= DateTime.Now`)

Comment: If I kept the parseDate method, I do agree that this is much cleaner than using a Tuple.  Then I would just adjust the `Where success` to `Where parsedDate.HasValue` to filter out the records where I can't parse the date (and therefore am not interested in).